# Increasing PHP Session lifetime. Possible side effects?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to increase the PHP session lifetime. After reading a couple of tutorials on the Internet and questions and answers on SO, I'm running out of ideas why it is not working on my system. Below the last tested code snippet from [this page](http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/manually-set-php-session-timeout-php-session/).

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',10*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);

$sessionCookieExpireTime = 10*60*60;
session_set_cookie_params($sessionCookieExpireTime);

session_start();

if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
  setcookie(session_name(), $_COOKIE[session_name()],
    time() + $sessionCookieExpireTime, '/');

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    session_destroy(); // executed at most 2 hours after login
header('Location: /login.php');
}

if (/*login-form sent*/) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'foo';
}
```

`ini_set` and `session_set_cookie_params` seem both to work:

before:

```
string(4) "1440"
array(5) {
  ["lifetime"] => int(0)
  ["path"] => string(1) "/"
  ["domain"] => string(0) ""
  ["secure"] => bool(false)
  ["httponly"] => bool(false)
}
```

after:

```
string(5) "36000"
array(5) {
  ["lifetime"] => int(36000)
  ["path"] => string(1) "/"
  ["domain"] => string(0) ""
  ["secure"] => bool(false)
  ["httponly"] => bool(false)
}
```

But after less than two hours, I am logged out. Is there any possibility of side effects that increasing the session lifetime does not work? I did some checks:

- the cookie lifetime is set correctly for ten hours
- the problem arises on all tested systems with different browsers, so it doesn't seem to be a local problem with the configuration of the browser
- When I refresh the same page (without requesting any other page inbetween) after > 2 hours, I cannot access the session variables anymore. But when I refresh after a bit more than 24 minutes (1440 seconds - default configuration in ini-file), the session still exists

Comment: What is the server OS? I know for a fact that Debian clean up the PHP session data with a cron job that works independently of `session.gc_maxlifetime`. As an aside, setting the GC probability to 1 is very wasteful and you should never do it.

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the server via SSH. I contacted the administrator. But if you're right, I should be able to fix it by keeping track of the time the session was created and destroy and recreate it manually every hour, right?